# Power apps- Add to media clips in attachment image to change background color

Tags: colors, background-image, powerapps

I make powerapps to image detection For receipt analaysis In AI programming.
I want to change attachment Image background color to white,
And I want to change attachment character in Image to black.
Because this way, I can detect character recognition.
Could you help to change attachment background color and character color??